# phpmyadmin can not connect to RDS database from my EC2 via phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

Before i could put the IP of my EC2 server and /phpmyadmin in my browser and i could sign into phpMyAdmin and view all my databases from the server (no problem). Then i ran a php script that connects to it like this:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("phpmyadmin.cvw71h2krjrb.us-east- 1.rds.amazonaws.com","phpMyAdmin","phpmyadmin") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Database connected.";

?>
```

i ran that script in my browser and it said "Database connected." so it connected. But once i tried to go back onto phpMyAdmin i got this error:

> ## 1045 - Access denied for user 'phpMyAdmin'@'172.31.56.54' (using password: YES)

I have a Android app that calls a different PHP script to insert data into my database in RDS. Heres the file:

```
<?php

require "init.php";

$user_name = $_POST["BuyerFirstName"];
$user_pass = $_POST["Password"];

$sql_query = "insert into user_info values('$user_name', '$user_pass');";

?>
```

I know the information is getting stored on the RDS because once i send the info from the app my CPU graph goes up in the dashboard.

i want to see if the data i send from my app actually gets stored on my RDS database but i cant sign into phpMyAdmin like before. what i am i doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The `mysql_connect` segment of code you posted wouldn't cause the Access denied error; there must be some other factor. Seeing a CPU spike doesn't necessarily mean the data was inserted; processing the connection attempt and rejecting an incoming connection also takes CPU cycles.

Does the first code snippet, the `mysql_connect` one, still work? If so, then you should use the same username, password, and host as you're connecting from in that script and try again.

If that doesn't work, you may need to ask your host to reset your password.

Comment: I fixed my error by restarting the whole process of setting up the server and database and i have everything running exactly how i want it but thank you for the answer. you were almost right ;)